# Sending mail from Excel Issue: Next without for

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble with my variable y. I'm getting the next without For error, when trying to run the macro.

```
Dim y As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Sht1.Cells(Sht1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In sht3.Columns("B").Select

    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

        With Outmail
        .to = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
        .Subject = "OE input sheet " & ActiveCell.Value & ": Service Delivered = NO"
        .body = "Hello " & ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Test" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

        For y = 2 To Lastrow
            Sht1.Range("B" & y).Select
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell.Value, sht3.Range("B:B"), 0) Then
                 .body = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value
        Next y
        .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set Outmail = Nothing

    End If

Next cell
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim y As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Sht1.Cells(Sht1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In sht3.Columns("B").Select

    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Value) Then

        With Outmail
        .to = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1)
        .Subject = "OE input sheet " & ActiveCell.Value & ": Service Delivered = NO"
        .body = "Hello " & ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Test" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

        For y = 2 To Lastrow
            Sht1.Range("B" & y).Select
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ActiveCell.Value, sht3.Range("B:B"), 0) Then
                 .body = ActiveCell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=-1).Value
            End If
        Next y
        .Send
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set Outmail = Nothing
Next cell
```